# Get the sum of a calculated expressions depends on template variable in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a simple array of numbers :

```
 data:Array<number> = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

And I also have an editable `input` which is a multiplication factor.

on the right side , I show the user the result  :

[image]

The html is pretty simple :

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let a of data">
            <td>{{a}}</td>
            <td><input type='text' #i [ngModel]="a" /></td>
            <td>{{i.value*a}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>-------<br/>sum ?</td>
        </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Please notice that the multiplication result is calculated via a template variable (`#i ----> i.value*a`)

**Question:**

But how can I calc the sum of that calculated column ?
I wonder if I can do it only via in the template.
Sure I can find solutions via TS.
But I wonder if I can do this only via template calculations

*nb
I've used `[ngModel]` and not banana since I need to show (in the input) the left side value at initialization , and if I'd do banana , when I'll change the input value , it would also change the left side value - which I don't want.*

[**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dy6hep?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: It's not possible in angular templates. The only solution is to move calculations from view layer to component or service and then display

Comment: @KarolTrybulec this means that I won't have ngModel , and I'd need to extract the value from the input in a manual way

Comment: `[()]` this syntax would help you, i guess. @RoyiNamir

Comment: @Jai I;m afraid it won't . At first I have to display the original value ( on the left side) and If I'd do this , when I'll change the input value , it will also change the left column. ( I didn't mention it because I thought it's not important to the question, but still ....). Thanks. ( EDITED)

Comment: Got it @RoyiNamir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddled my brain over this for half a day. Finally found a solution to the above.  `All value manipulations directly from html are often discouraged as these don't qualify as good code practices.` Nevertheless, I implemented the solution as follows. 
  Add the following in your `component.ts`.

```
data : Array<number> = [1,2,3,4,5];
sum  : Array<number> = [0];
```

Add the following code in your `component.html`

```
<table>
 <tbody>

  <ng-container *ngIf="{sample : sum} as variable">

   <tr *ngFor="let a of data;let index of index">
    <td>{{a}}</td>
    <td><input type='text' #i [ngModel]="a"/></td>
    <td>{{i.value*a}}</td>
    <td style="display:none;">{{variable.sample[index] = variable.sample[index-1]+i.value*a}}</td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td>Sum={{variable.sample[5]}}</td>
   </tr>

  </ng-container>

 </tbody>
</table>
```

Basically, I have used a `Array<number>` named `sum` which will hold the sum during each iteration of `ngFor`. I am calculatiing the same using `expression` inside the last `td` as `{{variable.sample[index] = variable.sample[index-1]+i.value*a}}`. For each iteration of the loop, the `sample` variable gets updated with the new sum. On any `change` of the `input` value the `sample` variable value also changes and this reflects as the Total.

Hope this helps. `A nice and challenging question it is, I must say!`.

**---EDIT1---**

The case was failing in case of non-consecutive numbers. Basically, `let a of data;let index of index` has two loop conditions. In the longhand notation, the condition evaluates to `<tr ngFor let-index="$implicit" ngFor let-a="$implicit" [ngForOf]="data">`  , which converts both `index` and `a` to implicit variables for the loop over `data`, thus meaning `index === a`. I have rectified the same as below. The following code works fine for all cases:

```
<table>
 <tbody>

  <ng-container *ngIf="{sample : sum} as variable">
    <tr  *ngFor="let a of data;let in=index">
     <td>{{a}}</td>
     <td><input type='text' #i [ngModel]="a"/></td>
     <td>{{i.value*a}}</td>
     <td style="display:none;">{{variable.sample[in+1] =variable.sample[in]+ i.value*a}}</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td>SUM={{variable.sample[data.length]}}</td>
    </tr>

  </ng-container>

 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. BTW what's `let index of index` ?  I know `let i=index`

Comment: It is the same as `let i=index`. Each index will be accessed with the variable name `index`. I used `index` as you have already used `i` to create a reference to the `input` tag

Comment: But here - your `index` is 1 based , not 0 based

Comment: I just checked. When you use `let index of index` or `let index:index`, the starting index is `1`. If you use `let index=index`, the starting index is `0`.

Comment: Now you can change [1,2,3,4,5] to [2,3,4,5,6] and see that it has nothing to do with starting index but rather you get `let index = $implicit` so `index === a`

Comment: @yurzui Hi. like you said , if I change it to [2,3,...] then it breaks. Is there other alternative ?

Comment: @JahnaviPaliwal Have you noticed  yurzui's comment?

Comment: Yes, I did. I am trying to check how to get a work-around for this. The `let index of index` is actually working as `index===a`. :(

Answer (score 1):

You need use [(ngModel)]. The problem when we use a ngModel with an array is that we can not iterate over the same array

```
   /***** This NOT valid ****/
    <tr *ngFor="let a of data;let i=index">
        <td><input type='text' [(ngModel)]="a" /></td>
    </tr>
```

See [Angular two way data binding in string array doesn't works correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52376943/angular-two-way-data-binding-in-string-array-doesnt-works-correctly)

So we need use an auxiliar variable

```
  //in ts
  data:Array<number> = [1,2,3,4,5];
  count:number[]=new Array(this.data.length); //<--this is the auxiliar variable

  //for the sum, I use a getter
  get sum()
  {
    let sum=0;
    this.data.forEach((p,index)=>{
      sum+=p*index
    })
    return sum;
  }
```

In .html

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of count;let i=index">
            <td>{{i}}</td>
            <td><input type='text' [(ngModel)]="data[i]" /></td>
            <td>{{i*data[i]}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>-------<br/>{{sum}}</td>
        </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: he said only via template calculation